# Undefined is not a function: jQuery and WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am stuck. I have used the following snippet outside of WordPress with success, have insured that jQuery IS being loaded, but am still getting the *'unexpected token = '*. I've tried removing the '$' from '$form', but then I get *'undefined is not a function'*. Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

```
<head>
  //added via wp_enqueue
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>
</head>
<body>
...
<form id="testForm" action="process-page.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" id="formSubmit" value="&nbsp;" />
</form>

<script>
// jQuery plugin to prevent double submission of forms
jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmission = function($) {
    $(this).on('submit',function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);
        if ($form.data('submitted') === true) {
          // Previously submitted - don't submit again
          e.preventDefault();
        } else {
          // Mark it so that the next submit can be ignored
          $form.data('submitted', true);
        }
    });
    // Keep chainability
    return this;
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('form').preventDoubleSubmission();
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you include your markup?

Comment: How are you including this script in your page?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: what line are you getting the error?

Comment: I am using  v1.11.1 and am getting the error on the line: var $form = $(this); It is actually stripping out the $form - only shows var = $(this)

Comment: I'm taking a stab at the $(this).on('submit',function(e) { ... being ambiguous, and have tried replacing that with jQuery('form').on('submit'... but am confused by the fact that this works outside WP

Comment: var = $(this) ??. Try go to 'view source' and see if the source has 'var $form=$(this)". It seems as if php is echoing the script, hence if $post has not been declared it leaves it as a blank..very odd. let me update my answer rather....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your custom jQuery function inside the `document ready` block so it is in a scope to use `$`. Like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $.fn.preventDoubleSubmission = function() {
        $(this).on('submit',function(e) {
            var $form = $(this);
            if ($form.data('submitted') === true) {
              // Previously submitted - don't submit again
              e.preventDefault();
            } else {
              // Mark it so that the next submit can be ignored
              $form.data('submitted', true);
            }
        });
        // Keep chainability
        return this;
    };

    $('form').preventDoubleSubmission();

});
```

Comment: Yes should work. Beat me to it, cos it works on the site I am currently working on.

Comment: That makes sense, but it still strips out the `$form` from `var $form = $(this)`... leaving me with the `unexpected token =` It only shows `var = $(this)`

Comment: I'd say then your problem lies elsewhere in your code, and not with the listed code, which I have tested and it works. That makes it difficult to try and guess what could be going wrong, but it really does sound like php is echo'ing the jscript to the document as I previously mentioned.

Comment: Yes, @Gavin Simpson, I am going to test something and will report back.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: I have found the unexpected token, which is in fact related to WP plugin making use of thickbox, but I still can't get the form button to disable after click. I have been able to create the page outside WP and get it work as at Kaloyan stated, so I'm continuing to trouble shoot.

Comment: I'm calling this good, since I can get it to work outside my situation.

Answer (score -1):

`jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmission = function() {`

should be

`jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmission = function($) {`"

methinks.

You should also not include jquery.js like this, but use enqeue rather. (`<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery');?>`).

Comment: Yes, I changed to your suggested `...function($) {` and I am using wp_enqueue, just added so the markup would be seen